# "Quantum Littlewood-Richardson" Rule?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

Let $\frak{g}$ be a complex semi-simple Lie algebra, and $\lambda,\mu \in P^+$ two positive dominant weights with corresponding irreducible representations $V(\lambda)$ and $V(\mu)$. The tensor product $V(\lambda) \otimes V(\mu)$ has the well-known decomposition into irreducible components given by the Littlewood-Richardson rule.

My question is whether or not this decomposition also exists in the quantum case, in other words, for the quantized enveloping algebra $U_q(\frak{g})$ with irreducible representations $V(\lambda)$ and $V(\mu)$, does $V(\lambda) \otimes V(\mu)$ have a "quantum Littlewood-Richardson" decomposition?

Comment: The Littlewood-Richardson rule is only for type A.

Comment: . . . a quantum version for $U_q(\frak{sl}_n)$ is fine for me.

Comment: @Milan: The answer to your question (which only involves type $A$ directly, as Tobias points out) depends on what your parameter $q$ is.  If it's an indeterminate, there is no difference between the decompositions in the classical and quantum cases, since the irreducibles are essentially the same.  But if $q$ is a root of unity, you get into trickier issues including "fusion rules".   I don't know any role there for Littlewood-Richardson as such.

Comment: I am interested in $q$ a non-root of unity complex number.

Comment: . . .  so what is a good reference for this please?

Comment: @Milan: You are right, I overlooked the question. My comment was deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there certainly is a quantum version of the Littlewood-Richardson decomposition (in the generic parameter case) for types $A,B,C,D$ (I don't know about the exceptional types). The generalized Littlewood-Richardson rule develops naturally out of a construction of crystal bases by semistandard tableaux (satisfying additional assumptions outside of type $A$).  Taking tensor products then amounts to adding or subtracting boxes to your Young diagram, and as a result you get Littlewood-Richardson in type $A$ and similar decompositions in the other types.

This view was (I believe) first elaborated by Kashiwara and Nakashima in '94 in the paper "Crystal graphs for representations of the $q$-analogue of classical Lie algebras", but a nice exposition is given in Chapter 8 of Hong and Kang's textbook "Introduction to Quantum Groups and Crystal Bases".